# Android Transition between Fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have an application that contains two fragments. A fragment (A) is a list of items and the toolbar has a search, and the second (B) is the datalhe the selected item. And can make the transition from A -> B and vice versa. My problem is in search of framgent A (the search is sequential, as if you type, the list is filtered taking into account the research field). Then click on the item to go to the delhalhe (and the toolbar is not the search, as I will), but when I wanted to keep back the open search with the text entered by the user.

Someone help me?

Comment: yes it is possible but what have you tried so far ?

Comment: A lot but always without success, then you can get here an excerpt of code with this implementation

Comment: I need to see the code of what you have tried. So, I may help you.

Comment: Now I have not any code with it. When nothing worked, deleted it.
There have asked for a code of graft to help me